# ASP.NET Core site hosted on IIS server needs to clear the cache of the browser each time in new updates

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application hosted in IIS server. Each time I update the site, I restart the application and recycle the application pool.

But new updates are causing a problem. The problem is that the application sometimes takes wrong data while executing different functions. But when I clear the cache of the browser (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Del</kbd>) the application works perfectly.

Is recycling the application pool not enough? Each time when I update the application the browser of the user needs to clear the cache. This is bothering the user. Is there any solution for this so that the user doesn't need to clear the cache every time in new update?

Comment: You'd better describe more about your web app, as merely ASP.NET Core is not enough context. Do you use ASP.NET Core MVC/Razor Pages or any front end JS frameworks like Angular/React? If the issue comes from browser side cache, debugging JavaScript on browser seems to be unavoidable to locate the culprit.

Comment: @LexLi I have been using ASP .NET Core Razor Pages and jQuery..